# Binary operator compatibility for shell

Tags: bash, shell, string-comparison, comparison-operators

I can't help noticing there are so many shell codes using comparison operators as `test` command's arguments, not with signs.

For example, to test if no arguments are received in shell using `test`:

```
if test $# -eq 0
then
    echo "No arguments received"
fi
```

Why can't we replace `-eq` with more, say, traditional, intuitive, familiar, universal, and, readable sign with `==`? So that we have the following:

```
if test $# == 0
then
    echo "No arguments received"
fi
```

The same goes with other comparison operators < <= => >.

I'm assuming there must be some technical reasons behind this (perhaps compatibility issue?) to favor `-eq` format over `==`, but I'm not aware of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, use `$#`, not `$@`.

The technical reason for the difference is that the operators define how the operands are interpretted.

For `<`, `=` and `>`, the operands are considered strings. This means that `10 < 2` because 1-something comes before 2-something in the alphabet, and `1 != 01` because the strings are of different lengths.

For `-eq`, `-gt`, `-lt`, the operands are considered integers. This means that `2 -lt 10` because the number 2 is smaller than the number 10, and `1 -eq 01` because these are both numerically equivalent ways of writing `1`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! What else would be the side effects of using string comparison operators for integer comparison?

Comment: It's mainly this -- alphabetical vs numerical order, and integer canonicalization. It's especially relevant in August because leading zeroes imply octal notation, and `date +%m` starts returning the invalid number `08`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `(( and ))` (**arithmetic processor**) in BASH that supports all the operators like `==`, `>=`, `<=`, `<`, `>` etc:

```
if (( $# == 0 ))
then
    echo "No arguments received"
fi
```

**PS:** # of parameters is represented by `$#`